# Localization in Drop down menu

Tags: jquery, spring, localization, internationalization

We have used Spring framework to build a web application, and we need to internationalize the app, we are easily able to internationalise static content using  '<'Spring: message'>'  tag and getting translated text from .properties file, **but we are really stuck on how-to internationalize dynamic elements e.g.:  drop down values, the drop down values are saved in database only for one language(English), which can and will be updated by admin any time,  so we cannot keep translated text in .properties files as it would mean hard coding.
Is there any other way around to internationalize drop down menu?**

**Drop down code:**

```
    DropdownForm dropdownForm = new DropdownForm();
    dropdownForm.setDropdownKey(Constants.DROPDOWN_QUALIFICATION);
    dropdownForm qualificationDropdown = DropdownService.getDropdown(DropdownForm);
    modelAndView.addObject("qualifications",qualificationDropdown.getDropdownValue());
```

jsp code:

```
<s:select path="qualifications[${count.index}].courseName" class="form-control required" data-width="100%" ">
 <s:option value="">Course Name</s:option>
 <s:options items="${qualifications}"/>
</s:select>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Hi @StanislavL,
Please take a look, i have modified the description.